# Does $f_n:[0,0.5]\to[0,0.5], f_n(x)=x^n$ uniformly converge to $f:[0,0.5]\to[0,0.5], f(x)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I am studying uniform convergence, and I am confused about this:

> Does $f_n:[0,0.5]\to[0,0.5], f_n(x)=x^n$ uniformly converge to $f:[0,0.5]\to[0,0.5], f(x)=0$?

My bet is that it does. I failed to see why it wouldn't. I suggested (to my friends with whom I am debating) $N=\left\lceil\frac{\log\epsilon}{\log x}\right\rceil$

As this must happen for all values of $x$, we choose the biggest $x=0.5$ for  $N=\left\lceil\frac{\log\epsilon}{\log x}\right\rceil$ because the larger the $x$, the slower $x^n$ gets shrunken. (Someone on a chat has said: "yes, that is true; but you can come up with an $N$ that doesn't depend on $x$" )
If the $x$ that shrinks the slowest has shrunk until the difference is less than $\epsilon$, all other $x$ will have already shrunken even more, so all of them uniformly shrink, and the difference is less than $\epsilon$ for $n\ge N$ for all $x$

To this, I got the reply "You don't need to prove pointwise convergence here. The only way to solve this dispute is to ask on math exchange"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is a special case of [Dini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to prove that that sequence converges uniformly to the null function, you have to prove that, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is some $N\in\Bbb N$ *depending only on* $\varepsilon$ such that$$n\geqslant N\text{ and }x\in\left[0,\frac12\right]\implies|x^n|<\varepsilon.\tag1$$But$$x\in\left[0,\frac12\right]\implies|x^n|\leqslant\frac1{2^n}.$$So, take $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $N>\log_2\left(\frac1\varepsilon\right)$ and then $(1)$ holds.